# Ubuntu 20.04 : unrecoverable unused space with GParted

Tags: 20.04, gparted, disk-usage

I have a 2TB SSD without OS on it, only data, it is on /dev/sda1. It is full but I have about 100GB that I cannot used on it. I have already extended at maximum with GParted.

df|grep /dev/sda1 returns :

/dev/sda1         1921802432 1824110376          0 100% /mnt/b85107de-9722-4bf5-8e9a-c810fbfb7e76

[here is GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjs6Z.png)

[here is the disk analyser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snR9z.png)

How to retrieve the unused space ?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The unuse space seems to be in the partition.  The only way to use it, is to fill with more data(not best idea) or to shrink partition and make new partition.  Partition must be unmounted before you can work on it.  100GBs left on 2TBs drive will read as full(<than 1%).  Would leave drive as is, since it probably keeps some GBs free for maintenance and get another drive.

Comment: the command sudo tune2fs -m 2 /dev/sda1 solved the problem, it reduced the reserved storage. Maybe 5% is quite high. Thanks a lot